# How to switch on receiving input in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, io

I am trying to write a node application that accepts user inputs, and blocks (or rather doesn't accept any input) while an AI is making their turn.

The following is the play() function in a module called 'play':

```
function play() {
welcome();

stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {
    var message = "";

    input = d.toString().trim();
    if(!expression.test(input)) {
        message = "Please enter a move of the form 'x, y' and press enter.\n";
        print_board(message);
        return;
    }

    input = input.replace(/ /g, "");
    user_move = input.split(",");

    if(valid_input()) {
        update_board();
        x_to_play = !(x_to_play);
    }
    else
        message = "Invalid move. Please try again.\n";

    print_board(message);
});
}
```

Clearly when a user provides input all goes well. But when the AI is playing I clearly wouldn't want the user to have to enter something, nor would I want them to be able to input anything whilst the AI was humming and ah-ing.

What would be the best way to solve the issue? I've tried using 'pause()', using a while loop, removing the listener and all listeners from stdin, but no luck. I keep getting issues about eventEmitter memory leaks when I try.

Comment: `if (ai.running) { print_board("The AI is currently running"); return; }`

Comment: Where would that line go? Within the call-back function? In play()?

Comment: In the stdin listener before you accept any other input.  It's not complete, you would need to expose a `running` property and set it to `true` whenever you start the "ai" and `false` whenever it completes.